# Finding the Mean, Variance and Marginal distribution of $X=Y_1+Y_2$ where $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent standard Normal random variables

Tags: statistics

Suppose $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent standard Normal random variables. $X$ is defined as

$$X=Y_1+Y_2$$

Find the Mean, Variance, and Marginal distribution of $X$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well known results for independent random variables: $E(Y_1+Y_2)=E(Y_1)+E(Y_2)=0$,  $\sigma^2(Y_1+Y_2)=\sigma^2(Y_1)+\sigma^2(Y_2)=2$.

The density function for the distribution of the sum is given by the following convolution $$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^\frac{{-u^2+(x-u)^2}}{2}du=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4}}$$

As you can see, $X$ is normal with mean $0$ and variance $2$.